# Is === in PHP binary-safe in string comparison?

Tags: php

Php functions `strcmp`, `strcasecmp` and other from this family are binary-safe.

Are operators `==` and `===` binary-safe?

And if yes what should be used in binary-safe string comparison: functions or operator?

(*binary-safe*: "operator or function that can be applied to variables without altering their current state")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Comparison operators are binary safe and == and ===(compares with type ) are comparison operators so they are .......

Answer (score 7):

They are, by your definition, but if you're comparing strings containing binary data, you should be aware of the fact that in PHP `$a == $b` can return true even when $a and $b are different. Example: `"2e2" == "200"`